# Distinct collection in mongodb with _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've a collections like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa6b5cced8d2cac81e7d7"),
    "stream" : "Programming",
    "coursename" : "java",
    "fee" : 50000,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-08-19T13:40:05.312Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa6d2cced8d2cac81e7d8"),
    "stream" : "Basic",
    "coursename" : "Msoffice",
    "fee" : 50000,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-08-19T13:40:34.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa6e0cced8d2cac81e7d9"),
    "stream" : "Basic",
    "coursename" : "Tally",
    "fee" : 80000,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-08-19T13:40:48.667Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa707cced8d2cac81e7da"),
    "stream" : "Programming",
    "coursename" : "C++",
    "fee" : 80000,
    "date" : ISODate("2019-08-19T13:41:27.556Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Here you can see Programming and Basic streams are duplicate. I want to distinct stream along with _id and stream fields inside it. So result would be 2 collections.
Ex:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa6b5cced8d2cac81e7d7"),
    "stream" : "Programming"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5aa6d2cced8d2cac81e7d8"),
    "stream" : "Basic"
}
```

`distinct` is returning only `stream` inside an array.

Comment: Erm, why don't you simply use `Programming` and `Basic` as `_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mongodb aggregation $group and $project stages will give expected result

```
db.exampleCollection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$stream",stream_id:{$first:"$_id"}}},{$project:{stream:"$_id",_id:'$stream_id'}}]);
```

Example result
[mongo_aggregation_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLxId.png)